# Placing variables in function defintion - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

New to python. I'm want to use a for loop, and have a range from 10 - 19 being placed into the function definition x^2 +1 for both f(x) & g(x). Tried to do the below with no success. Suggestions?

```
def f(x):
   return (x*2+1) 

def g(x):
   return (x*3+1)

for f(x) in range(10, 20):
    print x

for g(x) in range(10, 20):
    print x
```

Comment: `for x in range(10, 20): print f(x)`?

Comment: @mgilson Post it as an answer.

Comment: You may or may not get anything out of this, but the way my brain works would be to take a deep dive into why *(for example)* `for f(x) in  range(10): print(x)` is incorrect syntax. It's all in the python [grammar definition](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html) for the parser generator. The way to read it is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Answer (score 2):

You should switch variables and method expressions:

```
for x in range(10, 20):
    print f(x)

for x in range(10, 20):
    print g(x)
```

This will call `f(x)` and `g(x)` for each `x` (10, 11, 12, ..., 19) in the range respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your function calls should be

```
for x in range(10, 20): 
    print f(x)

for x in range(10, 20): 
    print g(x)
```

This way you are calling your function for every instance of `x` in the specified range, the way you are currently calling it makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

It is unclear what you mean saying

> I'm want to use a for loop, and have **a range from 10 - 19 being placed
>   into the function definition** x^2 +1 for both f(x) & g(x).

But if you mean the specified range is to be placed in the function definitions then for example you can alternatively define the functions the following way

```
def f( first: int, last: int ) -> int:
    for i in range( first, last + 1 ):
        yield i ** 2 + 1

def g( first: int, last: int ) -> int:
    for i in range( first, last + 1 ):
        yield i ** 3 + 1

for i in f( 10, 20 ): print( i, end = " " )
print()
for i in g( 10, 20 ): print( i, end = " " )
print()
```

The output of this code snippet looks like

```
101 122 145 170 197 226 257 290 325 362 401
1001 1332 1729 2198 2745 3376 4097 4914 5833 6860 8001
```

If the used Python does not support annotations then rewrite the definitions like

```
def f( first, last ):
    for i in range( first, last + 1 ):
        yield i ** 2 + 1

def g( first, last ):
    for i in range( first, last + 1 ):
        yield i ** 3 + 1
```